# Unable to Display Packet's Ethertype

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ethernet, packet-sniffers

So, I have a program to sniff packets, and so far it has been working very well. I am now trying to add additional functionality, but I keep running into problems when I try to decode the ethertype of a captured packet's Ethernet header. To isolate the location in which the error is occurring, I wrote a modified program to dump only the Ethernet header in hexadecimal, and then, using custom headers, decode the the source MAC address, destination MAC address, and ethertype, but this is the output:

```
Sniffing on device wlan0
308 BYTE PACKET
01 00 5e 00 00 fb 04 e5 36 4a 5d 3a 08 00       | ..^.....6J]:..
SRC 01:00:5e:00:00:fb DST 04:e5:36:4a:5d:3a TYPE 0000
328 BYTE PACKET
33 33 00 00 00 fb 04 e5 36 4a 5d 3a 86 dd       | 33......6J]:..
SRC 33:33:00:00:00:fb DST 04:e5:36:4a:5d:3a TYPE ff11
194 BYTE PACKET
01 00 5e 00 00 fb 04 e5 36 4a 5d 3a 08 00       | ..^.....6J]:..
SRC 01:00:5e:00:00:fb DST 04:e5:36:4a:5d:3a TYPE 0000
Captured 3 packets
```

Apparently, the program has no problem decoding the MAC addresses, which are the first twelve bytes of the fourteen byte header, but, for some reason, when it reaches the final two bytes comprising the ethertype, the program fails to display them properly. The first and third packets' ethertypes are 0x0800, or IP, and the second packet's ethertype is 0x86dd, or IPv6. I have tried displaying the ethertype in numerous formats, but none have yielded proper results.

These are the lines of code responsible for displaying the MAC addresses and ethertype:

```
ethernet_header = (const struct sniff_ethernet_hdr *)packet;
printf ("SRC %02x", ethernet_header->ether_shost[0]);
for (i = 1; i < ETH_ALEN; i++)
    printf (":%02x", ethernet_header->ether_shost[i]);
printf (" DST %02x", ethernet_header->ether_dhost[0]);
for (i = 1; i < ETH_ALEN; i++)
    printf (":%02x", ethernet_header->ether_dhost[i]);
printf (" TYPE %.4x", ethernet_header->ether_type);
printf ("\n");
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or notice any problems with the code?

EDIT: I continued to play with this program, and I discovered something strange. I set a pointer called eth_ptr to point to the thirteenth byte of the packet, where the ethertype begins. When I dereferenced this pointer and printed the result, it was, indeed, the first byte of the ethertype. So, I added a line to the program that prints the addresses of eth_ptr and the ethertype of the Ethernet header struct. These are the results:

```
Sniffing on device wlan0
104 BYTE PACKET
01 00 5e 00 00 fb 04 e5 36 4a 5d 3a 08 00       | ..^.....6J]:..
SRC 01:00:5e:00:00:fb DST 04:e5:36:4a:5d:3a TYPE 8
eth_ptr @ 0x7ffafd0b1944 ether_type @ 0x7ffafd0b194c
124 BYTE PACKET
33 33 00 00 00 fb 04 e5 36 4a 5d 3a 86 dd       | 33......6J]:..
SRC 33:33:00:00:00:fb DST 04:e5:36:4a:5d:3a TYPE 86
eth_ptr @ 0x7ffafd0b1944 ether_type @ 0x7ffafd0b194c
319 BYTE PACKET
01 00 5e 00 00 fb 04 e5 36 4a 5d 3a 08 00       | ..^.....6J]:..
SRC 01:00:5e:00:00:fb DST 04:e5:36:4a:5d:3a TYPE 8
eth_ptr @ 0x7ffafd0b1944 ether_type @ 0x7ffafd0b194c
Captured 3 packets
$ gdb -q
(gdb) p /x 0x7ffafd0b194c - 0x7ffafd0b1944
$1 = 0x8
```

The type that is being printed is really the dereferenced pointer, which points to the first byte of the ethertype. This pointer is located eight bytes before ethernet_header->ether_type in memory; therefore, the problem is that the ethertype element of the struct is located eight bytes ahead of where it is supposed to be. I do not know why this is, or how to fix this. Can anyone offer an explanation?

EDIT AGAIN: Well, I am a fool. I just took a close look at the Ethernet header structure:

```
struct sniff_ethernet_hdr
{
    uint8_t ether_shost[ETH_ALEN];
    uint8_t ether_dhost[ETH_HLEN];
    uint16_t ether_type;
} __attribute__ ((__packed__));
```

The macros:

```
#define ETH_ALEN        6
#define ETH_HLEN        14
```

After I fixed this careless mistake, the program ran flawlessly.

Comment: how does your sniff_ethernet_hdr struct looks like ?
and also you might have to use ntohs() on the short ether_type element, depending upon your processor architecture

Comment: The Ethernet header struct resembles any other:`struct sniff_ethernet_hdr
{
 uint8_t ether_shost[ETH_ALEN];
 uint8_t ether_dhost[ETH_HLEN];
 uint16_t ether_type;
};` And I tried ntohs, but it displayed the ethertype to be 4000, which, based on the raw header dump, it is not.

Comment: just to add that the ethernet vlan tagged packets have extra 4 bytes in the header in 2, 16 bit fields `vlan` and `tag` just in case you want to handle that.
http://wiki.wireshark.org/VLAN